# Android app in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i've searched for days but cant find an answer, perhaps you guys can help.

I'm creating an android app in eclipse, it all works just one thing is bugging me.

this is my main.java:

```
    package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Add Click listeners for all buttons
        View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_rassen);
        firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // Process the button click events
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
   case R.id.btn_rassen:
    Intent j = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
       j.putExtra(com.test.Webscreen.URL, 
         "http://www.google.com/");

       startActivity(j);

   break; 

   case R.id.button2:
    Intent k = new Intent(this, Webscreen.class);
       k.putExtra(com.test.Webscreen.URL, 
         "http://notworkingurltotest.com");
       startActivity(k);
   break;

  }  
 }
}
```

now when it calls the webview.java the page called shows up but not the buttons i created in the layout xml page. does anybody have any idea why this is?

your help is much appreciated!

ohw this is my webscreen.java

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Webscreen extends Activity {

    public static final String URL = "";
    private static final String TAG = "WebscreenClass";
    private WebView webview;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.webscreen);

        this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
        this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.string.webview);


        String turl = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
        Log.i(TAG, " URL = "+turl);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);


        final Activity activity = this;     

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Bezig met laden...");
                    progressDialog.show();

                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;


                }
            }


            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {



                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.Main");
                startActivity(myIntent); 

                Toast.makeText(activity, "Laden van onderdeel mislukt, probeer het later nog eens! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                progressDialog.show();
            }

            });




        webview.loadUrl(turl);

    }
}
```

webscreen.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <!-- <1> -->
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/url" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:lines="1"
      android:layout_weight="1.0" android:hint="http://"
      android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/go_button" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="go_button" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- <2> -->
  <WebView
        android:id="@string/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dip"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think we need some more information. For example what is the layout XML file for your Webscreen Activity?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply C0deAttack, very much appreciated, i added the layout code to my post.

Comment: if i comment out: 

WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

the button and textbar load but the page doesnt load anymore, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're creating a second webview and then setting that as the content view, so your R.layout.webscreen is replaced.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.webscreen);

    this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
    this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.string.webview);

    String turl = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    Log.i(TAG, " URL = "+turl);

    **WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);**
.....
```

Edit:

I've just noticed something in your code, should the line that reads:

```
this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.string.webview);
```

Acutally be:

```
this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.**id**.webview);
```

Edit 2:
Just noticed another thing while I was making the project. The following in webscreen.xml:

```
 android:id="@string/webview"
```

Should be:

```
 android:id="@+id/webview"
```

Edit 3:
And another thing noticed in webscreen.xml:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

Sure you want a 0 height?? ;-)

Comment: Posted this while you had replied. Ok, so the above is why you're buttons do not show, because you've replaced the view. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with how WebView works so I can't help with why the page doesn't load.

Comment: Ok, but if i remove those lines it doesnt show the webview. any suggestions on how to solve this? Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Just editted my original answer. If that's not the solution all I can suggest is that you check the WebView tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: i changed it to this.webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); but there is no difference.

Comment: I'm just copying your code in to a project, if I can recrate and fix the solution I'll post back in a short while.

Comment: would you rather have me upload the project?

Comment: Nah, I get to read it all as I copy it in. I just noticed something else, see Edit 2.

Comment: changed that when i changed the first edit already, really appreciate you looking into this by the way!

Comment: Notcied something else, See Edit 3.

Comment: hahaha, you just solved my problems! after removing **WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);** and setting the height it works like a charm, you are a true hero!

Comment: is there a way i can buy you a beer?

Comment: No worries Colin. I'll accept a virtual beer :) You just needed a fresh pair of eyes on your code. I learnt about WebView and WebViewClient so every one wins!

Comment: It was the last place i looked, and kept copying my webview when replacing linear layouts. Thanks loads and enjoy the rest of your day!